# Ajax result is success in sometimes and error in sometimes in different browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have a jsp page and I use `AJAX` to send data in jsp page to the database. I am working on `Spring framework`. The problem I have is once I run AJAX code to submit my data to the database, It does the stuff I need(submit my data to the database), but gives me the error alert in error section of the AJAX call, but only in `Google Chrome`. `Firefox` gives the alert message in success section. `Internet Explorer` gives me nothing. Whatever it alerts, there is no problem with the data insertion to the database. this is my ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function doAjaxPost() {

          var tot = $('#form1').find('.installmentAmount').length;

            var TotalNumberOfAmounts = parseInt(tot)-1;

            var pay_Date=[];
            var pay_Amount=[];
            var pay_No=[];



            try {
                for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumberOfAmounts; i++) {
                    var j = parseInt(i)+1;
                    //console.log(i);
                    pay_Date[i] = $('#dateOf_installment_'+j).val();
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumberOfAmounts; i++) {
                    var j = parseInt(i)+1;
                    pay_Amount[i] = $('#amountOf_installment_' + j).val();
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumberOfAmounts; i++) {
                    var j = parseInt(i)+1;
                    pay_No[i] = parseInt(j);
                }


            } catch (err) {
                alert("Error in JSP page is : "+err);
            }


            jQuery.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/TFProject/register5.htm",

                 data :  "pay_Date=" + pay_Date 
                + "&pay_Amount=" + pay_Amount
                + "&pay_No=" + pay_No
                + "&TotalNumberOfAmounts=" + TotalNumberOfAmounts, 

                success : function(response) {
                    // we have the response
                    items = response.result;
                     alert(response.result);
                    if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
                        var userInfo = "<ol>";


                        userInfo += "</ol>";

                        jQuery('#info').html("Officer has save successfully. ");
                        alert(" response SUCCESS!");


                        jQuery('#error').hide('slow');
                        jQuery('#info').show('slow');
                    } else {

                        alert(" response UNSUCCESS!");

                        errorInfo = "";

                        for (i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
                            errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) + ". "
                                    + response.result[i].code;
                        }
                        jQuery('#error').html(
                                "Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
                        jQuery('#info').hide('slow');
                        jQuery('#error').show('slow');
                    }
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    console.log('Error Error ERRRRRRR : ' + e);
                    alert('Error Error ERRRRRRRR : '+e);

                }
            });

        }
```

I am using `Spring Framework` for this project.I have a bean class related with this and it contains the variables required and they are encapsulated.

```
private String[] pay_Date;
private String[] pay_Amount;
private int[] pay_No;
private int TotalNumberOfAmounts;
```

Google Chrome gives the alert in this part.

```
error : function(e) {
  console.log('Error Error ERRRRRRR : ' + e);
  alert('Error Error ERRRRRRRR : '+e);
}
```

but `Firefox` gives first gives an error saying `object object` and then the success alert. Meanwhile `internet explorer` gives nothing. 
Why does this behave differently. What is the problem with my code.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error messages from all 3 browsers?

Comment: They are javascript alerts actually. in `chrome` it gives me the alert in `ajax` error section, which is ` alert('Error Error ERRRRRRRR : '+e);`. but in `firefox` it first gives a alert saying `object object` and then the `response success` alert which is generated from success section of the ajax. But in every case, data insertion to the database is successful.